# Can't Resize Photo in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, image-resizing

I need to resize photo when uploaded into path, but the photo can't resize, please correct me about my code here:

```
private function _do_upload()
 {

 $config['upload_path']    = './uploads/';
 $config['allowed_types']  = '*';
 $config['file_name']      = slug($this->input->post('judul')).'_'.time();
 $config['image_library']  = 'gd2';
 $config['quality']        = '20%';
 $config['remove_space']   = TRUE;
 $config['create_thumb']   = TRUE;
 $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
 $config['width']          = 75;
 $config['height']         = 50;

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();      
        $this->load->library('upload',$config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('photo')) {

          $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', $this->upload->display_errors('',''));
          redirect('backoffice/tambah_video');
    }
          return $this->upload->data('file_name');
}
```

Comment: Can you please show me which error you are getting ?

Comment: there no error, the uplaod is successfully but i can't resize the image

Comment: Have you tried after new_image path defined ?

Answer (score 0):

Please specify new image path and try to save.

```
$config['new_image'] = '/path/to/new_image.jpg';
```

Also make sure that you have  GD library enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `resize()` **after** `do_upload()`, and separate the configs for the `image_lib` and `upload` libraries, now they are mixed.
Try this:

```
private function _do_upload()
{
    // step 1: upload
    $upload_config['upload_path']    = './uploads/';
    $upload_config['allowed_types']  = '*';
    $upload_config['file_name']      = slug($this->input->post('judul')).'_'.time();

    $this->load->library('upload', $upload_config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('photo')) {
          $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', $this->upload->display_errors('',''));
          redirect('backoffice/tambah_video');
    }

    // step 2: resize
    $resize_config['source_image']   = $this->upload->upload_path . $this->upload->file_name; // uploaded file path
    $resize_config['image_library']  = 'gd2';
    $resize_config['quality']        = '20%';
    $resize_config['remove_space']   = TRUE;
    $resize_config['create_thumb']   = TRUE; 
    $resize_config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $resize_config['width']          = 75;
    $resize_config['height']         = 50;

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $resize_config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();

    return $this->upload->data('file_name');
}
```

If `$resize_config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;` the name of the small image will be suffixed `_thumb`.  If you need to overwrite the uploaded image, do `$resize_config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;`. See also the `thumb_marker` and `new_image` configs in the official documentation.